# adding fields in php wordpress

Tags: php, arrays, field

I would like to ask about a small change in the code for wordpress. I want to add more fields. For example: select field and few choices to select, or checkbox. I changed the type on select but then i realized i have no idea how to add choices for select field.

```
$fields['worker'] = array(
    'label'         => __( 'Surname', 'job_agent' ),
    'type'          => 'text',
    'placeholder'   => 'Surname',
    'description'   => '',
    'priority'      => 2
);
```

Thank You for Your time.

Comment: If you want to add those fields to pages in wp admin you can accomplish that with https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/

If you want to add those fields in customizer you will have to do some coding

Comment: Thank You about the plugin, now i have to find way how to import it into the plugin